# Laravel eloquent find in array from sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm developing a site with Laravel 4.2. I have two tables: **articles** and **tags**.

This is my **tags** table:

```
id | article_ids | xxxx
2  | 2,41,23,6   | xxxx
```

I'm using Eloquent and I want to find an specific id in article_ids column. 
How can I do this?

Can I search in MySQL like this?

Thanks for helping. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: bad table design, a table with one id per article_id makes much for sense

Comment: yea, but i want to learn this for another projects. It's important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much everything has been already said - bad design and you should avoid it and so on and so forth. That's true, I agree.

**Do it the right way**. However, here's how it's done in MySQL:

```
// say you want tags related to articles 2 and 23

SELECT * FROM tags
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', article_ids)
AND FIND_IN_SET('23', article_ids);

// Eloquent
Tag::whereRaw(
   'find_in_set(?, article_ids) and find_in_set(?, article_ids)',
   [$id1, $id2] // bindings array
)->get();
```

Comment: thx for answer, i'll do tags the right way. I just need learn this. Query is true, but how can i do this with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad way of associating tags with articles, as you've just discovered, because it cannot be easily queried against. Instead, for a many-to-many relationship between the two, you'll want an intermediate table with columns `article_id` and `tag_id`. For an article with four tags, there'd be four records, one for each association.

Comment: okey, this is so bad for tags. So, there is an another project for me. I'm trying message_groups and messages. i thought save users_id in message_groups's users column. And find who people in the message_group. Do you know best way for this?